# How to install the devise_security_extension gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I need to install the devise_security_extension gem. I performed the following steps:

1. added: gem 'devise_security_extension' to my gem file
2. ran bundle install
3. ran: rails g devise_security_extension:install

Apparently, there are some tables that need to be created, but I don't know how to create them as there is not a migration for them.

Comment: Though they don't explicitly state it, I'm assuming, based on their documentation, that you will need to do a `rake db:migrate` after you do the install part. Check the output after you run the install part and see if it indicates the creation of any db/migrate files.

Comment: https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension#schema

Comment: Teeg, that is my problem. It did not create any migration, so running db:migrate does nothing. It did added lines to devise initializer and the English and German localizations. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Zabba, I can see that the installation created a schema file. How do I use it. Sorry, I am a newbie on that.

Comment: `SCHEMA=<complete path to file> rake db:schema:load`

Comment: @Zabba Do you want to put that as an answer so Edmundo can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a schema file, you can load it using:

```
SCHEMA=<complete path to file> rake db:schema:load
```